# React native async storage update background notification in killed state

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using rnfirebase to receive firebase notifications on react-native. If app is in killed state, I am receiving notifications however the setBackgroundHandler is not getting called and no related tasks are working. Tasks such as adding data into AsyncStorage, increase the badge count and etc.

Comment: Did u find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this example listener, if the problem persists, please attach the code you use to implement the notifications. Also try using @notifee for better experience.

```
 type NotificationsListenersProps = {
   onNotification: (msg: FirebaseMessagingTypes.RemoteMessage) => void;
   onOpenNotification: (msg: FirebaseMessagingTypes.RemoteMessage) => void;
 };


 public createNotificationListeners(props: NotificationsListenersProps) {
    const { onNotification, onOpenNotification } = props;

    /** When the application is running, but in the background **/
    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(async remoteMsg => {
      if (remoteMsg) {
        if (!remoteMsg.notification) {
          onNotification(remoteMsg);
        } else {
          onOpenNotification(remoteMsg);
        }
      }
    });

    /** When the application is opened from the quit state **/
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(async remoteMsg => {
        if (remoteMsg) {
          if (remoteMsg.data) {
            onOpenNotification(remoteMsg);
          }
        }
      });

    /** When application is in quit state **/
    messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async () => {
      await this.incrementBadge();
    });

    /** Foreground messages **/
    messaging().onMessage(remoteMsg => {
      if (remoteMsg) {
        onNotification(remoteMsg);
      }
    });

    notifee.onForegroundEvent(({ type, detail }) => {
      if (type === EventType.PRESS) {
        if (detail.notification?.data) {
          const notification = { ...detail.notification };
          onOpenNotification(notification);
        }
      }
    });

    notifee.onBackgroundEvent(async ({ type, detail }) => {
      const { notification, pressAction } = detail;
      // Check if the user pressed the "Mark as read" action
      if (type === EventType.PRESS && notification) {
        onOpenNotification(notification);
      }
      if (notification && pressAction) {
        if (
          type === EventType.ACTION_PRESS &&
          pressAction.id === 'mark-as-read'
        ) {
          // Decrement the count by 1
          await notifee.decrementBadgeCount();
          // Remove the notification
          if (notification.id != null) {
            await notifee.cancelNotification(notification.id);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: are you suggesting to send data message only?

Comment: No, im just think that you have problems with listeners integration. Can you share your code, which includes firebase notifications integration.

Comment: I have setBackgroundMessageHandler in index.js which increases the badge count, updates async storage. However this doesn`t get called when app is in quit state, though notification is received. Event is called properly in background state.